# Equivalent 'grep' and 'sed' commands on Windows

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm doing some tests with a domain that I have, I want that, when doing the TXT query, receive a string in base64 and decode it showing the message.

On Linux, it works perfectly:

```
$ dig -t txt my.domain.com +short | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//' | base64 -d > file.txt
$ cat file.txt
```

testing out my txt records

Now I want to do the same thing, except that in Windows, by default Windows does not have dig, but it has a command that is the following:

```
C:\Users\User\xyz>powershell Resolve-DnsName my.domain.com -Type
TXT > test

C:\Users\Avell\xyz>type test

Name                                     Type   TTL   Section    Strings
----                                     ----   ---   -------    -------
my.domain.com                       TXT    10557 Answer    
{dGVzdGluZyBvdXQgbXkgdHh0IHJlY29yZHMK}
```

How could I adapt the command above (Linux) to work on Windows, taking only the stiring in base64 and decoding to show the message.

Comment: You can just download grep and sed for Windows.

Comment: Except for in restricted environments where network access is limited and security policy prevents the use of outside tools. "Just download a Windows version of <x>" is an obvious choice in unrestricted environments but there are a great many environments where that is not an option, hence the question.

Answer (score 5):

Or spend the needed time to learn PowerShell, by leveraging all the free resources and videos on Youtube to understand all the parts of PowerShell, and what can be done natively and when you need to code it yourself and when you need to pull in 3rdP tools.

This is not the first time this has been asked. A quick web search use 'PowerShell Sed' and 'PowerShell Grep', will show you a good list of these and even examples.

> Get-Content Gets the content of the item at the specified location.
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7
>
> Select-String Finds text in strings and files.
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7
>
> sed in PowerShell
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sergey_babkins_blog/sed-in-powershell
>
> PowerShell – UNIX SED Equivalent – Change Text In File
>
> https://www.kittell.net/code/powershell-unix-sed-equivalent-change-text-file
>
> Using sed and grep in PowerShell
>
> https://www.catapultsystems.com/blogs/using-sed-and-grep-in-powershell
>
> http://www.systemcentercentral.com/using-sed-and-grep-in-powershell
>
> Grep, the PowerShell way
>
> https://communary.net/2014/11/10/grep-the-powershell-way
>
> How to “grep” in PowerShell
>
> https://antjanus.com/blog/web-development-tutorials/how-to-grep-in-powershell
>
> How To Grep in PowerShell
>
> https://www.adamfowlerit.com/2017/02/how-to-grep-in-powershell
>
> Quick Tip: PowerShell Grep Equivalent
>
> https://dereknewton.com/2010/12/powershell-grep-equivalent
>
> POWERSHELL: SEARCH FOR STRING OR GREP FOR POWERSHELL
>
> https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2011/03/powershell-search-for-string-or-grep-for-powershell

Secondly, Leverage the [Microsoft powershellgallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/) directly in your PowerShell console or the new Windows Terminal ...

```
Find-Module -Name '*grep*' | Format-Table -AutoSize

Version Name     Repository Description                 
------- ----     ---------- -----------                 
1.1.0   PoshGrep PSGallery  Greplike PowerShell function



 Find-Package -Name '*grep*' | Format-Table -AutoSize

Name      Version        Source    Summary                                                                
----      -------        ------    -------                                                                
wk.Grep   0.2.0          nuget.org Package Description                                                    
Liv.Grep  1.0.5436.17982 nuget.org Grep utility written in c#. Makes it easy to query command line outputs
AstroGrep 4.3.2          nuget.org This application and its source code are freely distributable.         
GRepo     1.0.0          nuget.org GRepo                                                                  
PoshGrep  1.1.0          PSGallery Greplike PowerShell function
```

... or when using PowerShell editors - which provide popup help / IntelliSense ([PowerShell_ISE built-in](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-in-the-powershell-50-ise), [VScode download](https://code.visualstudio.com/), [PowerShell Plus](https://www.idera.com/productssolutions/freetools/powershellplus) which are free) or ([Sapien's PowerShell Studio](https://www.sapien.com/software/powershell_studio) - cost money.)

Lastly, you are using dig in your code as well. For that see this:

> [PowerShell: Query DNS Server for A, PTR, MX, NS and other records](https://techibee.com/powershell/powershell-query-dns-server-for-a-ptr-mx-ns-and-other-records/2570)
>
> [How to use PowerShell for DNS Records](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-dns/)